# Add item to tabBar of a tabPanel in extjs

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs4.2

I have a **static** tabPanel that i can't modify it. It has'nt any tabBar config. But i want to add some items to it's tabBar (add some buttons right of the tabPanel) with one of it's children panel. How can i do that? I'm using extjs 4.2.

my tabBar:

```
tabBar: {
    items: [{
        xtype: 'tbfill'
    }, 
    {
        itemId : 'completeButton',
        iconCls : 'icon-complete',
        xtype: 'button',
        text: 'complete'
    }, {
        itemId : 'diagramButton',
        iconCls : 'icon-diagram',
        xtype: 'button',
        text: 'diagram'
    }]
}
```

code to add item to tabBar:

```
//childPanel is a direct child of rootTabPanel
//button is a button that should be added to rootTabPanel tabBar
addButton2Toolbar : function(childPanel,button){
    var rootTabPanel = childPanel.up('tabpanel');
    // add button to tabBar of rootTabPanel ?????
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'v added a fieldcontainer item to tabBar and move tabBars items to fieldcontainers items.

```
tabBar: {
    items: [{
        xtype: 'tbfill'
    }, {
        xtype : 'fieldcontainer',
        itemId : 'toolBar',
        layout : 'hbox',
        items : [ {
            itemId : 'completeButton',
            iconCls : 'icon-complete',
            xtype: 'button',
            text: 'complete'
        }, {
            itemId : 'diagramButton',
            iconCls : 'icon-diagram',
            xtype: 'button',
            text: 'diagram'
        }]
    }]
}
```

code to add item to tabBar:

```
//childPanel is a direct child of rootTabPanel
//button is a button that should be added to rootTabPanel tabBar
addButton2Toolbar : function(childPanel,button){
    var rootTabPanel = childPanel.up('tabpanel');
    var toolBar = rootTabPanel.down('fieldcontainer#tabBar');
    toolBar.add(button);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this! I had to implement something very similar and this was a perfect solution!